# How to turn an array to a CSV string based on commas?

Tags: javascript, csv

I have a function which returns a CSV string to be consumed by

```
anchorEle.href = `data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,${encodeURI(csvContent)}`
```

If I have an array like this:-

```
[
    [
        "Test,Me,Once,More",
        "Successful"
    ],
    [
        "Test1,Me1,Once1,More1",
        "Successful"
    ]
]
```

The construction of CSV string messes up when I have commas in my item. I cannot set a condition based on the number of commas because it's not fixed as a user requirement.
I'm using the following function:-

```
function toCsv(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((csvString, row) => {
    csvString += row.join(',');
    csvString += '\r\n';
    return csvString;
  }, '');
}
```

This will return:-

```
Test,Me,Once,More,Successful
Test1,Me1,Once1,More1,Successful
```

Which when I download as CSV [image]


I wish to club *Test, Me, Once, More* as one item in CSV keeping the commas as it is like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dee J. Doena has stated, you should apply quotes `""` to all string values. This snippet gives a simple short example of iterating an array of arrays and returning a CSV string;

```js
let arr = [ [ "Test,Me,Once,More", "Successful", 123 ], [ "Test1,Me1,Once1,More1", "Successful", 234 ] ];

let csvConvert = () => {
    return arr.flatMap(t => t.map(o => typeof o  === "string" ? `"${o}"` : o).join(",")).join("\n")
}

let anchorEle = document.getElementById("csvLink")
anchorEle.href = `data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,${encodeURI(csvConvert())}`;
```

```html
<a id="csvLink" href="#">Download CSV</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

RFC 4180 specifies that when you use the delimiter character in your fields (in your case it's the comma), you need to enclose the field in double quotation marks

In your case your text file output needs to look like this:

```
"Test,Me,Once,More",Successful
"Test1,Me1,Once1,More1",Successful
```

You can even enclose the `Successful` in double quotes.

You also need to use double quotes when having a line break in your cell but don't expect all CSV interpreters (e.g. Excel) to import line-break cells properly.